# How to return only objects with targeted parameters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

For example I have this `POST` method:

```
request_salaries(type)
```

`type` can be `red`, `blue` or `green`.

The function returns this object:

```
{
  data: [
    {
     id: 1,
     name: "Linda",
     type: "Red"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Mark",
      type: "Green
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Susan",
      type: "Blue"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I need to return only the sat of data that is passed in the `request_salaries(type)`.

For example, if I request `request_salaries(`Red`)`

it should return:

```
{
  data: [
    {
     id: 1,
     name: "Linda",
     type: "Red"
    },
  ]
}
```

How can this be achievable?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just filter out proper values:

```
const response = { /* your data */ };
const type = 'red';

const filteredResponse = response.data.filter(item => item.type === type)
```

Comment: Also don't forget to assign that `filter` array to a new value, `filter` returns an array of items matching the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter your returns

```
request_salaries(type){

// fetch data and set it in array_salaries


return array_salaries.filter(salary => salary.type == type)



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.find()`:

```js
var obj = {
  data: [
    {
     id: 1,
     name: "Linda",
     type: "Red"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Mark",
      type: "Green"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Susan",
      type: "Blue"
    }
  ]
};
var val = 'Red';
var res = obj.data.find(({type}) => type===val);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.find()` method

```
var type = 'red';

const result = response.data.find(function(item) {
    return item.type === type;
});
```

Using arrow function:

```
const result = response.data.find( item => item.type === type );
```